# What happens to AdSense revenue after the YouTube threshold change?

Tags: youtube, google-adsense

I worked hard on my YouTube channel to be granted monetisation. I earned a bit but not a huge amount. YouTube have since changed the requirements for monetisation and I no longer meet the criteria. It's going to take a lot of work in order to meet those criteria. Checking my AdSense account the payment threshold is 60 GBP. I have about 30 GBP in there. As I said it's not a lot but I'm wondering what will happen to that money?

Answer (score 1):

> As I said it's not a lot but I'm wondering what will happen to that money?

It'll sit there. If you have some website you're monetizing, you'll be able to go above the payment threshold eventually. If you meet the criteria again, you'll go above the threshold eventually.

If you aren't doing either and don't think you ever will, you can close your AdSense account. As you are above the [cancellation threshold](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1709871), you'll get a final payment of whatever is left on your balance.

Comment: Fwiw, it's worth a lot. I put 2 and 2 together and got 3. I'll edit to remove that reference.